# Jquery animate left on hover not working perfectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

I have created a script that moves an li to the left 40px on mouseenter and moves it back on mouseleave. It works fine most of the time, however it will often glitch so that it moves to the left and does not record mouseleave, so it will stay 40px to the left. Then when you mouseenter again, it will move a further 40px. This ends up with a misaligned list .

misaligned list Image -

[image: misaligned list Image]

Here is the html and jquery :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".work ul li a").on("mouseenter", function() {
    $(this).animate({
      left: "-=40px",
    }, 200)
  });
  $(".work ul li a").on("mouseleave", function() {
    $(this).animate({
      left: "+=40px",
    }, 200)
  });
  $("#darl").on({ 
    mouseenter: function() {
      $("#bgimg1").fadeIn(200);
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      $("#bgimg1").fadeOut(200);
    }
  });
  $("#chil").on({ 
    mouseenter: function() {
      $("#bgimg2").fadeIn(200);
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      $("#bgimg2").fadeOut(200);
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="work">
  <h1 class="heading">Selected Projects</h1>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <ul>
    <li id="darl">
      <div class="container2"><div class="block">
        <img class="bg-image"  id="bgimg1" src="Images/perspective2final2pfolio2.jpg">
        </div></div>
      <a href="">1. Darlington Terrace</a>
    </li>

    <li><div class="thinline"></div></li>
    <li id="chil">
      <div class="container2"><div class="block">
        <img class="bg-image"  id="bgimg2" src="Images/DSC_0756.jpg">
        </div></div>
      <a href="">2. Children's Playground</a>
    </li>

    <li><div class="thinline"></div></li>
    <li>
      <div class="container2"><div class="block">
        <img class="bg-image"  id="bgimg3"src="Images/perspective2final2pfolio2.jpg">
        </div></div>
      <a href="">3. Lawn Bowl Bakery Bridge</a>
    </li>

    <li><div class="thinline"></div></li>
    <li>
      <div class="container2"><div class="block">
        <img class="bg-image"  id="bgimg4"src="Images/perspective2final2pfolio2.jpg">
        </div></div>
      <a href="">4. Aqueduct: Museum of Architecture</a>
    </li>

    <li><div class="thinline"></div></li>
    <li>
      <div class="container2"><div class="block">
        <img class="bg-image"  id="bgimg5"src="Images/perspective2final2pfolio2.jpg">
        </div></div>
      <a href="">5. Velocity Frequent Flyer Website</a>
    </li>

    <li><div class="thinline"></div></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Here is the github repo: https://github.com/mingweichan/CVwebsite

Comment: did you try to add .stop() with animate, fadeIn, fadeOut ? .....

$(this).stop().animate() and so on.... I hope this will solve the issue

Comment: .stop() just made it worse :/

Comment: `stop()` would stop the animation midway, instead you should use `finish()` which would stop the animation immediately and css properties are set to the target values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered this sometime ago, you will want to add a `.stop()` before calling `.animate` because it seems to me jQuery registers each event and puts them into a stack and iterates through every item in the stack.

In other words, if you move your mouse over and out of the element 10 times quickly, the events will fire 10 times.

However for your case add a `.stop()` will fix one problem but because you're using relatives values to animate the `left` property it doesn't seem to complete the animation before the next event is fired. I suggest using absolute values:

```
$(".work ul li a").on("mouseenter", function() {
  $(this).stop().animate({
      left: "-40px",
  }, 200)
});
$(".work ul li a").on("mouseleave", function() {
  $(this).stop().animate({
      left: "0px",
  }, 200)
});
```

Comment: Not stack, jQuery uses animation Queues.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem with using absolute values for the left properties is that the page will not be responsive, and when you resize the window to mobile (around 600px) it will not work properly. Unless I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: @Ming you can use `%` values if you want the movement to scale

Comment: @jkris Thanks! I needed to do marginLeft -40px and then 0px. Combined with finish() made it work!

Answer (score 1):

So based on the other helpful answers, here is what worked for me:

```
$(".work ul li a").on("mouseenter", function() {
    $(this).finish().animate({
        marginLeft: "-40px",
    }, 200)
});
$(".work ul li a").on("mouseleave", function() {
    $(this).finish().animate({
        marginLeft: "0px",
    }, 200)
});
```

Instead of 'left' I used marginLeft so that it would still work in a responsive layout. And I used finish() to make sure that it would stop the animation immediately rather than queuing the animation multiple times. Thanks for all the help guys!